# How to browse the code for adobe flash animation

Tags: adobe-flash, actionscript

When I create a new ActionScript 3.0 animation in Adobe Flash does it built some source code building along with my animation?

I found that there is an object oriented programming language called ActionScript much like Java syntax wise. So, if Adobe Flash automatically build that source code of an animation how might I watch the ActionScript souce code of my .fla file?

Comment: Thanks for the question and welcome to GraphicDesign! If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not at all what ActionScript (AS) is. AS is used inside Flash (.fla) files to do programmatic elements such as buttons, jump frames, create movie clip instances and all sorts of other complex tasks. You would have to code it into your animation for it to exist and would appear as a keyframe with a lowercase "a" on it.